# Rewrite rule when source contains a '?'

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http, regex

Scratching my head on this. I have an old URL:

```
     http://myserver/blog/archive?openview&type=Category&key=Demo
```

and a new URL

```
     http://myserver/blog/categories/Demo
```

I'm trying to get a rewrite rule for this. I thought it would be:

```
     ^/blog/archive\?openview&type=Category&key=(.*) /blog/categories/$1.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

But that doesn't do anything. I tried the URL and rule (replace the ? with /):

```
     http://myserver/blog/archive/openview&type=Category&key=Demo
     ^/blog/archive/openview&type=Category&key=(.*) /blog/categories/$1.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

And that works as expected. So I'm a bit dumbfolded how to handle the ? for matching in the old URL.
All the samples I found describe the opposite case. Sending the "pretty" URL to the ugly one. In my case the "ugly" URL is what people in the past had bookmarked and I want to make sure they get to the new data properly

Comment: Excellent link. Thxs for adding it here!

Answer (score 2):

A little thinking (and reading [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)) later:

The mod_rewrite matches use the location part of the URL only. The "?" marks the end of the location and the beginning of the parameters (a.k.a QueryString). Once I realized that, it was just [a Google away](http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html).

So to transform correctly you need a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^openview&type=Category&key=(.*)    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog/archive$ /blog/categories/%1.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

Works like a charm